# Define a custom color variable

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to change some button colors globally in my code. I cannot seem to fine a way to define a color variable and then assign a color value to that variable.

I tried this
          Color SelectedColor = new Color();

```
      f1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 100));
```

I want to use ColorSelected in place of the RGB value so I can edit the value at start up.

```
          f1.setBackgroundColor(Color.ColorSelected);
```

Comment: Please consider reading the documentation(or even hints shown by eclipse on hover). `setBackgroundColor()` taken an `integer` argument. The way you are using `SelectedColor`(as a static member of `Color`) is wrong. Second, `setBackgroundColor` cannot take `Color` object as an argument. Use a resource id instead. Define a color as `blackbelt` has suggested. Then, use `f1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.definedColorName))`.

Comment: What if he needs create colors dynamically? "Depending on light sensor readout change background color"

Answer (score 38):

you can use `values/colors.xml`. For instance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="menu_background">#666666</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Android Studio doesn't add the file colors.xml when creating a new project, so I added my custom color to strings.xml, but when using it as @string/mycolor the app halts. Now it works with colors.xml.

Comment: neither Eclipse creates that file. The file has to be created manually, @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez

Answer (score 11):

> "I cannot seem to fine a way to define a color variable and then assign a color value to that variable."

Here is how you can define a color variable:

```
int selectedColor = Color.rgb(0, 0, 100);
```

and use it:

```
f1.setBackgroundColor(selectedColor);
```

Answer (score 5):

You must add attribute  `type="color"`  in the color tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color type="color" name="menu_background">#666666</color>
</resources>
```

So, you can use the color in xml file as `"@color\menu_background"`
and also from java code.