# Are colors like "green" hardcoded in Color.parseColor() or do they use values from R.color?

Tags: android, android-color

According the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String)) Color.parseColor not only accepts hex values but also the color names *red*, *blue*, *green*, *black*, *white*, *gray*, *cyan*, *magenta*, *yellow*, *lightgray*, *darkgray*, *grey*, *lightgrey*, *darkgrey*, *aqua*, *fuchsia*, *lime*, *maroon*, *navy*, *olive*, *purple*, *silver*, and *teal*.

Are the values of those hardcoded or can I customize which kind of *green* gets produced?

Comment: You can define any color in `color.xml` with Hex code and use it in code [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750506/define-a-custom-color-variable) .. And those Colors are like `Color.RED` are hardcoded...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's [take a look at source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/Color.java) of `parseColor()` within `android.graphics.Color`:

```
@ColorInt
public static int parseColor(@Size(min=1) String colorString) {
    if (colorString.charAt(0) == '#') {
        // Use a long to avoid rollovers on #ffXXXXXX
        long color = Long.parseLong(colorString.substring(1), 16);
        if (colorString.length() == 7) {
            // Set the alpha value
            color |= 0x00000000ff000000;
        } else if (colorString.length() != 9) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown color");
        }
        return (int)color;
    } else {
        Integer color = sColorNameMap.get(colorString.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT));
        if (color != null) {
            return color;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown color");
}
```

So firstly the first character of the string is checked for a `#`, symbolising if we're using an RGB or ARGB value. But we're not interested in that, so skip to the `else` statement where we're looking to see if the `colorString` argument matches a key within `sColorNameMap`:

```
static {
    sColorNameMap = new HashMap<>();
    sColorNameMap.put("black", BLACK);
    sColorNameMap.put("darkgray", DKGRAY);
    sColorNameMap.put("gray", GRAY);
    sColorNameMap.put("lightgray", LTGRAY);
    sColorNameMap.put("white", WHITE);
    sColorNameMap.put("red", RED);
    sColorNameMap.put("green", GREEN);
    sColorNameMap.put("blue", BLUE);
    sColorNameMap.put("yellow", YELLOW);
    sColorNameMap.put("cyan", CYAN);
    sColorNameMap.put("magenta", MAGENTA);
    sColorNameMap.put("aqua", 0xFF00FFFF);
    sColorNameMap.put("fuchsia", 0xFFFF00FF);
    sColorNameMap.put("darkgrey", DKGRAY);
    sColorNameMap.put("grey", GRAY);
    sColorNameMap.put("lightgrey", LTGRAY);
    sColorNameMap.put("lime", 0xFF00FF00);
    sColorNameMap.put("maroon", 0xFF800000);
    sColorNameMap.put("navy", 0xFF000080);
    sColorNameMap.put("olive", 0xFF808000);
    sColorNameMap.put("purple", 0xFF800080);
    sColorNameMap.put("silver", 0xFFC0C0C0);
    sColorNameMap.put("teal", 0xFF008080);

}
```

So if we get a match, that colour ARGB value is returned (some named ARGB values are defined as `@ColorInt int` constants at the top of the class). If not, then an `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown.

So to answer your question, yes, these values are hardcoded. If you want to use your own values, define them within your app's `colors.xml` file.